# java jprogressbar hangs during heavy operation

Tags: java, multithreading, progress-bar, jprogressbar

I'm writing a java program and, before I call a method that makes heavy use of the CPU, I display a frame with a JProgressBar on it. Although I display it before the method is called, the JProgressBar is not shown until the method is over. The progress bar does not interact with the method in any way (yet) and that's why I am confused. It is something like:

```
progressbarframe.setVisible(true); // it is a indeterminate progress bar
heavyLoadMethod();
progressbarframe.dispose();
```

The frame shows, but the progress bar doesn't initialize during the method. Is there any way I can solve this without using threads? What would be the simplest way?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the `heavyLoadMethod` in a separate thread. You can use a `java.util.concurrent.Executor` for it:

```
Executor executor = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(new Runnable() { public void run() { heavyLoadMethod();}});
```

Now the method will be called in a separate thread and the progress bar will be displayed properly.

Comment: it worked like a charm, I never used threads without using a whole class and using the "implement runnable" thing. Thank you for your idea

Comment: You should explore the `java.util.concurrent` package. It has many high level concurrency utilities.

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the EDT from repainting the GUI.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for a full explanation of the problem.

Also, read the section on "How to Use Progress Bars" for a working example.